# Remove parent <div> tag end of </div> closing tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, tags

Consider this my value:

```
var value = "<br><br><div class="test">-- Thanks, <br><div><br></div></div>";
```

I want to remove test class div tag i.e `<div class="test1">` and related to closing tag `</div>`.

Expecting results will be:

```
"<br><br>-- Thanks, <br><div><br></div>"
```

I am trying with regular expression:

```
value = value.replace(/(<div class="test">|<\/div>)/g, '');
```

but it's removing adjacent div tag:

```
<br><br><div class="test">-- Thanks, <br><div><br>
```

not the exactly with the closing tag.

How to do this?

Comment: Have you looked into .unwrap? https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Comment: [Don't use regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/157247). Just don't.

Comment: Are you doing this on a browser?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet here is to use the HTML parser built into the browser. For instance:

```
var div, divToRemove, node, sibling;
div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = value;
divToRemove = div.querySelector('.test');
for (node = divToRemove.firstChild, sibling = node.nextSibling;
     node;
     node = sibling, sibling = node && node.nextSibling) {

     divToRemove.parentNode.insertBefore(node, divToRemove);
}
divToRemove.parentNode.removeChild(divToRemove);
value = div.innerHTML;
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var value = '<br><br><div class="test">-- Thanks, <br><div><br></div></div>';
snippet.log("Before: " + value);
var div, divToRemove, node, sibling;
div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = value;
divToRemove = div.querySelector('.test');
for (node = divToRemove.firstChild, sibling = node.nextSibling; node; node = sibling, sibling = node && node.nextSibling) {
  divToRemove.parentNode.insertBefore(node, divToRemove);
}
divToRemove.parentNode.removeChild(divToRemove);
value = div.innerHTML;
snippet.log("After: " + value);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. T.J Crowder!! 

You used div.innerHTML, so implicitly it'll  execute it in browser. this is case hackers may handle the html string content right? Please let me know if i am correct or not.

Comment: @Premkumar: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: Okay, Let me rephrase different way. basically my html string is secure mail content, at this case if we use innerHTML (div.innerHTML = value;) Is it the correct way to do ? that's what my concern is.

Comment: @Premkumar: Did you mean *insecure* email? If the HTML is coming from an untrusted source, you don't want to hand it to the browser. That would be **really** important information to put in the question. Instead, you'd want to use any of several HTML "sanitizing" libraries to only allow through content you have a high degree of trust in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first save parent div's html in a variable

```
var html = document.getElementByClassName('test1').innerHtml;
```

Then remove the div:

```
document.getElementByClassName('test1').remove();
```

Then append the html to the parent of the div

```
var bodyHtml = document.getElementByTagName('body');

bodyHtml = bodyHtml + html;
```

Comment: Look again at the question: The OP is dealing with HTML markup in a string.

Comment: Thanks Mr. T.J Crowder!! 

You used div.innerHTML, so implicitly it'll  execute it in browser. this is case hackers may handle the html string content right? Please let me know if i am correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DOM to get it right

```
var html = '<br><br><div class="test">-- Thanks, <br><div><br></div></div>';
var frag = document.createElement('div');
frag.innerHTML = html;
var tgt = frag.querySelector('.test');
var par = tgt.parentNode;
while(tgt.firstChild) {
    par.insertBefore(tgt.firstChild, tgt);
};
tgt.remove();
console.log(frag.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Jarmanda!! 

You used div.innerHTML, so implicitly it'll  execute it in browser. this is case hackers may handle the html string content right? Please let me know if i am correct or not.

Comment: no idea what you are saying about hackers - the above possibly works in nodejs if you use jsdom

Comment: I am using dojo framework,
Let me rephrase different way. basically my html string is secure mail content, at this case if we use innerHTML (div.innerHTML = value;) Is it the correct way to do ? that's what my concern is.

Comment: which is a client side thing, right? so no need for jsdom

Comment: Yes, it's client side. The above code is perfectly working.
Did you get my concern about div.innerHTML. basically i am worrying to use innerHTML here. is there any alternative way to resolve it.

Comment: why are you concerned about using innerHTML of an element you create but never add to the DOM?

Comment: yes.Thanks Jaromanoda! Let me check with my higher officials.

Comment: @JaromandaX: Creating an element still has potential side-effects, such as retrieving external resources. If Premkumar is saying that the HTML content is *insecure* (from an untrusted source), then your answer and mine (which are essentially the same thing) are both problematic. (The fact the HTML comes from an untrusted source, if true, **really** should have been in the question, of course.)

Comment: well, yes, the example code looks benign - I've not tested it, but what's the worst that can happen with an element not added to the DOM? no javascript gets executed does it? do images even get loaded?

Comment: well, scripts in innerHTML don't seem to get executed, but images in img tags do get loaded